# Is there a way to test my nonce validation fails when it should?

Tags: php, wordpress, security, validation, nonce

I'm using nonce validation in a wordpress plugin. When I submit the form from the admin menu it processes correctly, so I believe the nonce validation is working. What I'm not sure is if the validation will fail when it is supposed to and I don't know what the best way to test this is.

I tried putting the url for the php file in directly, but all it does it take me to a wordpress not found page.

Is there some recommended way to test this?

Here is my code. Again, the test passes when it is supposed to, I just don't know if it fails when it is supposed to.

```
if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $ecbs_post_data['_wpnonce'], 'ecbs-edit-templates' ) ) {
    wp_die( __( 'You do not have permission to update this page.' ) );
}
```

Comment: you can create different users and different permissions to test

Comment: Put different names to the created and the checked nonce.

Comment: Thanks brasofilo, that worked.